# Including c++ libraries (opencv) on remote build raspberry pi

Tags: c++, linux, opencv, netbeans

I'm stuck trying to get some openCV code working on my raspberry pi. I'm almost certain the problem is caused by the linker not knowing where the openCV library files are but I'm unfamiliar with both Linux and Netbeans so I'm in a bit of a pickle!

So, in short, my set-up is: attempting to build my code to my raspberryPi via remote C++ build host (G++). I am writing my code in Netbeans.

The builds worked fine up until the point I wrote two new classes using the "opencv2/core/core.hpp"

Now, when I attempt to build, I get the following error/s:

```
Copying project files to /home/pi/.netbeans/remote/192.168.1.99/desktop-g6lev01-Windows-x86_64 at pi@192.168.1.99
Building project files list...
Checking directory structure...
Checking previously uploaded files...
Checking links...
Uploading changed files:
    Zipping 1 changed files...
    Uploading zip to pi@192.168.1.99...
    Unzipping changed files...
Checking exec permissions...
Uploading changed files finished successfully.

cd '/home/pi/.netbeans/remote/192.168.1.99/desktop-g6lev01-Windows-x86_64/E/Work/RasberryPi/Code/Raspberrypi_Test'
/usr/bin/make -f Makefile CONF=Release
"/usr/bin/make" -f nbproject/Makefile-Release.mk QMAKE= SUBPROJECTS= .build-conf
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/pi/.netbeans/remote/192.168.1.99/desktop-g6lev01-Windows-x86_64/E/Work/RasberryPi/Code/Raspberrypi_Test'
"/usr/bin/make"  -f nbproject/Makefile-Release.mk IOTestBuild
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/pi/.netbeans/remote/192.168.1.99/desktop-g6lev01-Windows-x86_64/E/Work/RasberryPi/Code/Raspberrypi_Test'
g++ -o IOTestBuild build/Release/GNU-Linux/CommsManager.o build/Release/GNU-Linux/ImageManager.o build/Release/GNU-Linux/Server.o build/Release/GNU-Linux/main.o -L../../opencv- -lwiringPi -opencv
build/Release/GNU-Linux/ImageManager.o: In function `ImageManager::getStoredImg()':
ImageManager.cpp:(.text+0xcc): undefined reference to `cv::Mat::copySize(cv::Mat const&)'
build/Release/GNU-Linux/ImageManager.o: In function `ImageManager::ImageManager()':
ImageManager.cpp:(.text+0x134): undefined reference to `cv::VideoCapture::VideoCapture()'
ImageManager.cpp:(.text+0x1c0): undefined reference to `cv::Mat::deallocate()'
ImageManager.cpp:(.text+0x288): undefined reference to `cv::Mat::deallocate()'
ImageManager.cpp:(.text+0x2b8): undefined reference to `cv::fastFree(void*)'
ImageManager.cpp:(.text+0x2c0): undefined reference to `cv::VideoCapture::VideoCapture()'
ImageManager.cpp:(.text+0x32c): undefined reference to `cv::VideoCapture::~VideoCapture()'
ImageManager.cpp:(.text+0x344): undefined reference to `cv::Mat::copySize(cv::Mat const&)'
ImageManager.cpp:(.text+0x350): undefined reference to `cv::Ptr<CvCapture>::delete_obj()'
ImageManager.cpp:(.text+0x358): undefined reference to `cv::fastFree(void*)'
ImageManager.cpp:(.text+0x36c): undefined reference to `cv::VideoCapture::~VideoCapture()'
ImageManager.cpp:(.text+0x388): undefined reference to `cv::VideoCapture::~VideoCapture()'
build/Release/GNU-Linux/ImageManager.o: In function `ImageManager::~ImageManager()':
ImageManager.cpp:(.text+0x3a0): undefined reference to `cv::VideoCapture::~VideoCapture()'
ImageManager.cpp:(.text+0x404): undefined reference to `cv::fastFree(void*)'
ImageManager.cpp:(.text+0x414): undefined reference to `cv::Mat::deallocate()'
build/Release/GNU-Linux/ImageManager.o: In function `ImageManager::getRawImg(cv::Mat*)':
ImageManager.cpp:(.text+0x43c): undefined reference to `cv::VideoCapture::open(int)'
ImageManager.cpp:(.text+0x450): undefined reference to `cv::VideoCapture::operator>>(cv::Mat&)'
ImageManager.cpp:(.text+0x494): undefined reference to `cv::VideoCapture::release()'
build/Release/GNU-Linux/ImageManager.o: In function `ImageManager::updateFrame()':
ImageManager.cpp:(.text+0x5f0): undefined reference to `cv::Mat::copySize(cv::Mat const&)'
ImageManager.cpp:(.text+0x67c): undefined reference to `cv::fastFree(void*)'
ImageManager.cpp:(.text+0x6b8): undefined reference to `cv::Mat::deallocate()'
ImageManager.cpp:(.text+0x6c4): undefined reference to `cv::Mat::deallocate()'
build/Release/GNU-Linux/ImageManager.o: In function `cv::Mat::~Mat()':
ImageManager.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv3MatD2Ev[_ZN2cv3MatD5Ev]+0x68): undefined reference to `cv::fastFree(void*)'
ImageManager.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv3MatD2Ev[_ZN2cv3MatD5Ev]+0x74): undefined reference to `cv::Mat::deallocate()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
nbproject/Makefile-Release.mk:65: recipe for target 'IOTestBuild' failed
make[2]: *** [IOTestBuild] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/pi/.netbeans/remote/192.168.1.99/desktop-g6lev01-Windows-x86_64/E/Work/RasberryPi/Code/Raspberrypi_Test'
nbproject/Makefile-Release.mk:62: recipe for target '.build-conf' failed
make[1]: *** [.build-conf] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/pi/.netbeans/remote/192.168.1.99/desktop-g6lev01-Windows-x86_64/E/Work/RasberryPi/Code/Raspberrypi_Test'
nbproject/Makefile-impl.mk:39: recipe for target '.build-impl' failed
make: *** [.build-impl] Error 2

BUILD FAILED (exit value 2, total time: 701ms)
```

Any ideas?

I'm sure I just need to point the linker to the appropriate libs but I've no idea how to specify that relative path when using a build host.

Regards

Guy

Comment: Ok, so I changed my linker 'libraries' field from '-opencv' to 'opencv' and the undefined reference errors have been resolved! Yay.

However, I'm still stuck with the 'recipe for target' errors, I take it they are unrelated?

(EDIT: Upon looking at the new error message, it says that 'opencv' no such file or directory - So I may have just hidden the errors)

Comment: please update your Q so people can read only what is necessary to help. Good luck.

Comment: I think my changes didn't actually solve the issue - i.e. rather than fixing the errors, they created a new error ("opencv - no such file or directory") which had the effect of hiding the others. Probably better to disregard my comment than change the error in the Q. :)